# How do I add CSS code to source code in Umbraco?

Tags: html, css, umbraco

The website that I work with, I only have access to source code which is using HTML (and Umbraco website). I would like to add some changes in CSS, is there someway to "hack" this thing?

Comment: have you tried to add <style> tag in html ? with `important` where needed to overwrite already defined styles

Comment: Yes, Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS [In-Line](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) style. It works everytime but the cons are that you have to manually modify every element instead of using an external stylesheet full of elements (classes, id's, tags..)